# Function exports in Node.js show up as properties in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

This isn't technically wrong, so I didn't file as a bug on GitHub, but it seems like there should be better behavior (or perhaps a better way I can define exports).

Say I have:

```
function one() {
    // do stuff
}

function two() {
    one()
}

module.exports = {one, two};
```

In another file when I require this module, both `one` and `two` show up as object properties (blue icons). VSCode doesn't seem to recognize that they are in fact functions. This is the same behavior if you define named anonymous functions such as `module.exports = {one: function () {}};` which makes sense when written that way. But if I simply want a function to show up as a function in exports, the only way I can seem to make it work is:

```
module.exports = {
   one() { /* do stuff */ },
   two() { /* do more stuff */},
};
```

This works in some cases, but if `two` needs to call `one` and both functions need exported, you must use `this.` to access the other members.

How can I define a bunch of functions in a module that can utilize each other, and also export them all so that they show up as functions (purple icon) in other modules in VSCode?

## EDIT

The issue here is getting VSCode to recognize and hint functions as such when requiring them from other modules, instead of them showing up as 'properties' of the module.

Comment: I don't see any difference (from Javsscript's point of view) between your two `module.exports` statements.  They both accomplish the exactly same thing.  Both are exporting an object with two properties and the value of each property is a function.  So, I guess this is entirely a question about a blue icon in VSCode.

Comment: From Javascript point of view it both works the same, however in VSCode, it labels them as (property) with a blue icon in the first example, and as (method) with a purple icon in the second example. When you call functions from within the same file they are labeled (function) in purple, so it seems there should be a way to make exported functions appear the same to differentiate exported variables and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can allow you to export your functions and call your local functions :

```
let self = {
  one: function() {
    return 'one';
  },
  two: function() {
    return self.one();
  }
};
module.exports = self;
```

On the other hand, if your blue icon still not displaying, you could name your functions:

```
let self = {
  one: function SayOne() {
    return 'one';
  },
  two: function CallOne() {
    return self.one();
  }
};
module.exports = self;
```

Finally, you can import your functions this way :

```
const { one, two } = require('./your_file');
console.log(two());
```

Comment: Your first example does avoid losing the `this` context when de-structuring functions on import, and maintains the correct intellisense, so I will accept this answer. It's still annoying that just defining functions in the module scope and then exporting them, VSCode can't figure out that they're functions, and not just properties of the module.exports object. I think I'll open a ticket on VSCode's Github.